# Hide Account Funds Top Up in My Account from WooCommerce 'Customer' Role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have a Woocommerce subscription site so most of my customers roles are `Subscriber`. Now I want to offer some free mini-trials with a bit of credit to potential customers who would be a `Customer` role as we haven't reached them signing up for a subscription yet.

The problem is the Account Funds (plugin: WooCommerce Account Funds by WooCommerce) shows in their "My Account" area allowing them to deposit say $10 if they wanted and bypass a subscription. How can I hide this from their view via perhaps a Woocommerce Hook?

Below is the source code for that relates to 'My-Account' for the paid Account Funds plugin, taken from `/includes/class-wc-account-funds-my-account.php`

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/**
 * WC_Account_Funds_My_Account
 */
class WC_Account_Funds_My_Account extends WC_Query {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'add_endpoints' ) );
        add_filter( 'the_title', array( $this, 'change_endpoint_title' ), 11, 1 );

        if ( ! is_admin() ) {
            add_filter( 'query_vars', array( $this, 'add_query_vars' ), 0 );
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', array( $this, 'add_breadcrumb' ), 10 );
            add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this, 'pre_get_posts' ), 11 );

            // Inserting your new tab/page into the My Account page.
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', array( $this, 'add_menu_items' ) );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_account_account-funds_endpoint', array( $this, 'endpoint_content' ) );

            add_action( 'wp', array( $this, 'topup_handler' ) );

            if ( function_exists( 'WC' ) && version_compare( WC()->version, '2.6', '<' ) ) {
                add_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', array( $this, 'my_account' ) );
            }
        }

        $this->init_query_vars();
    }

    /**
     * Init query vars by loading options.
     *
     * @since 2.0.12
     */
    public function init_query_vars() {
        $this->query_vars = array(
            'account-funds' => get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_account_funds_endpoint', 'account-funds' ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Adds endpoint breadcrumb when viewing account funds.
     *
     * @since 2.0.12
     *
     * @param  array $crumbs already assembled breadcrumb data
     * @return array $crumbs if we're on a account funds page, then augmented breadcrumb data
     */
    public function add_breadcrumb( $crumbs ) {
        foreach ( $this->query_vars as $key => $query_var ) {
            if ( $this->is_query( $query_var ) ) {
                $crumbs[] = array( $this->get_endpoint_title( $key ) );
            }
        }

        return $crumbs;
    }

    /**
     * Check if the current query is for a type we want to override.
     *
     * @since 2.0.12
     *
     * @param  string $query_var the string for a query to check for
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function is_query( $query_var ) {
        global $wp;

        $is_af_query = false;
        if ( is_main_query() && is_page() && isset( $wp->query_vars[ $query_var ] ) ) {
            $is_af_query = true;
        }

        return $is_af_query;
    }

    /**
     * Get endpoint title.
     *
     * @since 2.0.12
     *
     * @param  string $endpoint Endpoint name
     * @return string           Endpoint title
     */
    public function get_endpoint_title( $endpoint ) {
        $title = '';
        if ( 'account-funds' === $endpoint ) {
            $title = __( 'Account Funds', 'woocommerce-account-funds' );
        }

        return $title;
    }

    /**
     * Changes page title on account funds page.
     *
     * @since 2.0.12
     *
     * @param  string $title original title
     * @return string        changed title
     */
    public function change_endpoint_title( $title ) {
        if ( in_the_loop() ) {
            foreach ( $this->query_vars as $key => $query_var ) {
                if ( $this->is_query( $query_var ) ) {
                    $title = $this->get_endpoint_title( $key );
                }
            }
        }
        return $title;
    }


    /**
     * Insert the new endpoint into the My Account menu.
     *
     * @since 2.0.12
     *
     * @param array $items
     * @return array
     */
    public function add_menu_items( $menu_items ) {
        // Try insert after orders.
        if ( isset( $menu_items['orders'] ) ) {
            $new_menu_items = array();
            foreach ( $menu_items as $key => $menu ) {
                $new_menu_items[ $key ] = $menu;
                if ( 'orders' === $key ) {
                    $new_menu_items['account-funds'] = __( 'Account Funds', 'woocommerce-account-funds' );
                }
            }
            $menu_items = $new_menu_items;
        } else {
            $menu_items['account-funds'] = __( 'Account Funds', 'woocommerce-account-funds' );
        }

        return $menu_items;
    }

    /**
     * Endpoint HTML content.
     *
     * @since 2.0.12
     */
    public function endpoint_content() {
        $topup    = '';
        $products = '';
        if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'account_funds_enable_topup' ) ) {
            $topup = $this->get_my_account_topup();
        } else {
            $products = $this->get_my_account_products();
        }

        $recent_deposits = $this->get_my_account_orders();

        $vars = array(
            'funds'           => WC_Account_Funds::get_account_funds(),
            'topup'           => $topup,
            'products'        => $products,
            'recent_deposits' => $recent_deposits,
        );

        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/account-funds.php', $vars, '', plugin_dir_path( WC_ACCOUNT_FUNDS_FILE ) . 'templates/' );
    }

    /**
     * Fix for endpoints on the homepage
     *
     * Based on WC_Query->pre_get_posts(), but only applies the fix for endpoints on the homepage from it
     * instead of duplicating all the code to handle the main product query.
     *
     * @since 2.0.12
     *
     * @param mixed $q query object
     */
    public function pre_get_posts( $q ) {
        // We only want to affect the main query
        if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( $q->is_home() && 'page' === get_option( 'show_on_front' ) && absint( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) !== absint( $q->get( 'page_id' ) ) ) {
            $_query = wp_parse_args( $q->query );
            if ( ! empty( $_query ) && array_intersect( array_keys( $_query ), array_keys( $this->query_vars ) ) ) {
                $q->is_page     = true;
                $q->is_home     = false;
                $q->is_singular = true;
                $q->set( 'page_id', (int) get_option( 'page_on_front' ) );
                add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', '__return_false' );
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Handle top-ups
     */
    public function topup_handler() {
        if ( isset( $_POST['wc_account_funds_topup'] ) && isset( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'account-funds-topup' ) ) {
            $min          = max( 0, get_option( 'account_funds_min_topup' ) );
            $max          = get_option( 'account_funds_max_topup' );
            $topup_amount = wc_clean( $_POST['topup_amount'] );

            if ( $topup_amount < $min ) {
                wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'The minimum amount that can be topped up is %s', 'woocommerce-account-funds' ), wc_price( $min ) ), 'error' );
                return;
            } elseif ( $max && $topup_amount > $max ) {
                wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'The maximum amount that can be topped up is %s', 'woocommerce-account-funds' ), wc_price( $max ) ), 'error' );
                return;
            }

            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ), true, '', '', array( 'top_up_amount' => $topup_amount ) );

            if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
                wp_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ) );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show funds on account page
     */
    public function my_account() {
        $funds = WC_Account_Funds::get_account_funds();

        echo '<h2>'. __( 'Account Funds', 'woocommerce-account-funds' ) .'</h2>';
        echo '<p>'. sprintf( __( 'You currently have <strong>%s</strong> worth of funds in your account.', 'woocommerce-account-funds' ), $funds ) . '</p>';

        if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'account_funds_enable_topup' ) ) {
            $this->my_account_topup();
        } else {
            $this->my_account_products();
        }

        $this->my_account_orders();
    }

    /**
     * Get HTML string for topup form in my account.
     *
     * @since 2.0.12
     *
     * @return string HTML string
     */
    public function get_my_account_topup() {
        ob_start();
        $this->my_account_topup();
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    /**
     * Show top up form
     */
    public function my_account_topup() {
        $min_topup     = get_option( 'account_funds_min_topup' );
        $max_topup     = get_option( 'account_funds_max_topup' );
        $items_in_cart = $this->_get_topup_items_in_cart();
        $topup_in_cart = array_shift( $items_in_cart );
        if ( ! empty( $max_topup ) && ! empty( $topup_in_cart ) ) {
            printf(
                '<p class="woocommerce-info"><a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s</p>',
                wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ),
                __( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce-account-funds' ),
                sprintf( __( 'You have "%s" in your cart.', 'woocommerce-account-funds' ), $topup_in_cart['data']->get_title() )
            );
            return;
        }

        $vars = array(
            'min_topup' => $min_topup,
            'max_topup' => $max_topup,
        );

        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/topup-form.php', $vars, '', plugin_dir_path( WC_ACCOUNT_FUNDS_FILE ) . 'templates/' );
    }

    /**
     * Get topup items in cart.
     *
     * @since 2.0.6
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function _get_topup_items_in_cart() {
        $topup_items = array();

        if ( WC()->cart instanceof WC_Cart && ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
            $topup_items = array_filter( WC()->cart->get_cart(), array( $this, 'filter_topup_items' ) );
        }

        return $topup_items;
    }

    /**
     * Cart items filter callback to filter topup product.
     *
     * @since 2.0.6
     *
     * @return bool Returns true if item is topup product
     */
    public function filter_topup_items( $item ) {
        if ( isset( $item['data'] ) && is_callable( array( $item['data'], 'get_type' ) ) ) {
            return ( 'topup' === $item['data']->get_type() );
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Show top up products
     */
    private function my_account_products() {
        $product_ids = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => 'deposit',
                )
            ),
            'fields' => 'ids'
        ) );
        if ( $product_ids ) {
            echo do_shortcode( '[products ids="' . implode( ',', $product_ids ) . '"]' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get HTML string of deposit products in my account page.
     *
     * @since 2.0.12
     *
     * @return string HTML string
     */
    private function get_my_account_products() {
        ob_start();
        $this->my_account_products();
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    /**
     * Show deposits
     */
    private function my_account_orders() {
        $deposits = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => 10,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
            'post_status' => array( 'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold' ),
            'meta_query'  => array(
                array(
                    'key'   => '_funds_deposited',
                    'value' => '1',
                )
            )
        ) );

        if ( $deposits ) {
            $vars = array(
                'deposits' => $deposits,
            );
            wc_get_template( 'myaccount/recent-deposits.php', $vars, '', plugin_dir_path( WC_ACCOUNT_FUNDS_FILE ) . 'templates/' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get HTML string of recent deposits.
     *
     * @since 2.0.12
     *
     * @return string HTML string
     */
    private function get_my_account_orders() {
        ob_start();
        $this->my_account_orders();
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}

new WC_Account_Funds_My_Account();
```

Comment: Hi, can you share the template 'myaccount/topup-form.php'?
Surely you can override this file in your theme and then add an if(role=='customer')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to disable/hide the *topup form* is by copying the "Account Funds" template (`myaccount/account-funds.php`) from the plugin folder *to your theme* folder — i.e. copy this file:

```php
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-account-funds/templates/myaccount/account-funds.php
```

to:

```php
wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/account-funds.php
```

And then find and change the following:

```php
<?php echo $topup; ?>
```

to:

```php
<?php
// If the current user is **not** a "customer", show the topup form.
if ( ! current_user_can( 'customer' ) ) {
    echo $topup;
}
?>
```

See full code [here](https://gist.github.com/5ally/df333b4a89d635688a0225c0e0206d33). (for "WooCommerce Account Funds" version 2.1.16)

You could also instead edit the topup form template itself (`myaccount/topup-form.php`) [like this](https://gist.github.com/5ally/a7ede4ad1ab57fc8847b24682f374e9e).

---

And I'd also add this to the theme functions file:

```php
// If the user is a "customer", bypass the action which handles top-ups.
add_action( 'wp', function(){
    if ( isset( $_POST['wc_account_funds_topup'] ) && current_user_can( 'customer' ) ) {
        unset( $_POST['wc_account_funds_topup'] );
    }
}, 0 );
```